# C++ store formatting in stringstream

Tags: c++, formatting, stringstream

I want to store a number's formatting in a `std::string`, but it doesn't work as I hoped it would.

The code explains what I mean:

```
long long l = 3184900000;
std::cout.imbue(std::locale("de_DE.utf8"));

// output: '3.184,90' <- ok, nice! how to get this into a string?
std::cout << std::right << std::put_money(l / 10000, true);

std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::right << std::put_money(l / 10000, true);
// output: '318490' <- nope.
return ss.str(); // <- so the return value is unformatted as well.
```

Please let me know how to get this working. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Working code.

```
long long l = 3184900000;
std::stringstream ss;
ss.imbue(std::locale("de_DE.utf8"));
ss << std::right << std::put_money(l / 10000, true);
return ss.str();
```

Comment: Remember that a `std::stringstream` object is a stream object just like `std::cout`, with it's own locale setting and all.

Comment: ss.imbue(std::locale("de_DE.utf8"));

Comment: nice, thanks! right in the moment you answered I had the idea :D